# Regexp to find name from email address

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this sample data

```
akb.ggb@yahoo.com           should output         akb ggb
sdsd.sdsd@gmail.com         should output         sdsd sdsd
asdasd.asasd@tmail.com       should output        asdasd asasd
```

I need a regexp to find fullname from email like above.

Any help should be appreciated.

Comment: what language are you using the regex from

Comment: i an using this in ruby helper method

Comment: First you need to match the email address. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703060/valid-email-address-regular-expression/703068#703068 has a regular expression that can do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^[^@]*` will output `akb.ggb`
you will then need to split by the '.' character...

the regex syntax is obviously programming language dependent.

`^([^\.@]+)\.*([^@]*)` will in both ruby and java place in group-1 (capture-1) the first name, and in group-2 (capture-2) the surname (if it exists).

You can play with regex online:
[Ruby](http://rubular.com/)
[Java](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us your language, but in java, it would look like:

```
"akb.ggb@xyx.com".replaceAll("@.*", "").replace(".", " "); // "akb ggb"
```

This will work for any number of "names", eg input of [`alfred.e.neuman@mad.com`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_E._Neuman) would result is `"alfred e neuman"` (three words)