# Regular Expression For Email in Ruby?

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to validate the email I tried the below expression

(/\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9a-z-]+.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}\z/)

But if some one giving email like xyx@domain.com@domain1.com by mistake it takes this also a valid email. Please help me to get the exact regular expression for email in ruby.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is an extra field that we need to validate manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Valid email address regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703060/valid-email-address-regular-expression)

Comment: @prasvin Rails doesn't do email validation? If it does, post a docs link please.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [mail](http://rubygems.org/gems/mail) gem to parse any string according to RFC2822 like so:

```
def valid_email( value )
  begin
   value return false if value == ''
   parsed = Mail::Address.new( value )
   return parsed.address == value && parsed.local != parsed.address
  rescue Mail::Field::ParseError
    return false
  end
end
```

This checks if the email is provided, i.e. returns `false` for an empty address and also checks that the address contains a domain.

The mail gem is already included in Rails, so you can use the code above anywhere in your application.

Comment: Did you know any regular expressions for the same purpose?

Comment: The mail gem actually parses the email according to RFC and is quite strict. If you just need to do some basic format checking you could use the Regex used in Authlogic gem https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/regex.rb

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in ruby's email regexp `URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP`

Just add the 
`validates_format_of :user_email, with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP` in the model

Also, you can enhance the regexp using a different one, see @Daniel suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to check if a particular string is a valid email address or not in Ruby.

You want to start by creating a constant variable that stores your regular expression.

There are countless resources with Regex cheat sheets that you can incorporate for matchers.

Here is the regular expression code that will verify that a string matches the common pattern followed by email addresses.

`VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A([\w+\-].?)+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i`

If you look at this expression, the first part allows names, numbers, dashes and dots. This is followed by ensuring the `@` symbol is used. And lastly this is followed by a `a` and letters. This is typically in the format `something@domain.extension`. At the end we are ensuring that the matcher is case insensitive with `/i`.

To build a method that verifies this pattern

```
def is_valid_email? email
  email =~ VALID_EMAIL_REGEX
end
```

The above method is called `is_valid_email?` and we are passing it an argument called `email`.

Next, we are checking this parameter against the `VALID_EMAIL_REGEX` constant to return `true` of `false`. Then you can check some use cases:

```
p is_valid_email?("jon@kinney.com") ? "Valid" : "Invalid"
p is_valid_email?("jonkinney.com") ? "Valid" : "Invalid"
p is_valid_email?("jon.k@kinney.com") ? "Valid" : "Invalid"
p is_valid_email?("jon@kinney") ? "Valid" : "Invalid"
```

Executing this code should output:

```
"Valid"
"Invalid"
"Valid"
"Invalid"
```

The first and third email addresses are valid because they match the pattern, while the second and fourth are invalid.

Don't forget to enclose the arguments in your ternary operator in parentheses.