# combine two assignments in one line and pep8 style python code

Tags: python, regex, pep8

```
  email = re.search('(.*?)-+(.*?)-+', line).group(1)
  password = re.search('(.*?)-+(.*?)-+', line).group(2)
  user_data.write("%s\t%s\n" % (email, password))
```

how to combine the first and second line into one line?

another question:

```
email = re.search("[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?\^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*", line)
```

how should I split the line into two lines?

Comment: If you want to ask another question, ask another question. Don't edit more questions into this one.

Comment: And yes, [the regex required to correctly parse an email address is incredibly complex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703060/valid-email-address-regular-expression). You are better off protecting against obvious user error and going from there.

Comment: ok,I know one post on question.

Comment: @young001: Someone edited your question to correct your spelling and you edited it back? What does the word "combile" mean?

Comment: joel,when someone edit my question,I editing it the same time,and when I saved,it override editor's effort.:-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`groups()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups):

```
email, password = re.search('(.*?)-+(.*?)-+', line).groups()
```

Comment: Wow, how did I not see that one. +1, this is a better answer.