# How can I find an email address inside HTML code with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, nokogiri

How can I find an email address inside HTML code with Nokogiri? 
I supose I will need to use regex, but don't know how.

Example code

```
    <html>
    <title>Example</title>
    <body>
    This is an example text.
    example@example.com
    </body>
    </html>
```

There is an answer covering the case when there is a href to mail_to, but that is not my case. The email addresses are sometimes inside a link, but not always.

Thanks

Comment: This is definitely *not* a Nokogiri question, it's a text parsing question in ruby. I tagged it with `Ruby` and `regex` to improve your responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're just trying to parse the email address from a string that just so happens to be HTML, Nokogiri isn't needed for this.

```
html_string   = "Your HTML here..."
email_address = html_string.match(/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i)[0]
```

This isn't a perfect solution though, as the RFC for what constitutes a 'valid' email address is *very* lenient. This means most regular expressions you come across (the above one included) do not account for edge case **valid** addresses. For example, according to the RFC

```
$A12345@example.com
```

is a valid email address, but will not be matched by the above regular expressions as it stands.

- Suggested Reading: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx
- Regex source: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/ruby-method-extract-emails

Comment: Why this really is not a perfect solution is that it finds only the first email address on the page

Comment: This **is** a perfect solution *for the question asked here*. The question had nothing to do with parsing *multiple* addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a regex on the HTML string, no need for Nokogiri (as @deefour suggested). For the regex itself, I'd suggest the one (called `AUTO_EMAIL_RE`) used by the [rails autolink gem](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink/blob/master/lib/rails_autolink/helpers.rb#L81):

```
/[\w.!#\$%+-]+@[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+/
```

This should catch those edge cases that stricter regex filters miss:

```
RE = /[\w.!#\$%+-]+@[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+/

RE.match('abc@example.com')
#=> #<MatchData "abc@example.com">

RE.match('$A12345@example.com')
#=> #<MatchData "$A12345@example.com">
```

Note that if you really want to match *all* valid email addresses, you're going to need a [mighty big regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703060/valid-email-address-regular-expression#703068).