# How should I find and replace all the email addresses in www folder using Notepad++

Tags: regex, email, notepad++, phpstorm

I need to update all the email addresses in my PHP/Codeigniter project placed in www folder. Can anybody tell me how should i get all type of emails by using Notepad++ or PhpStorm editors? I know this can be done by using regular expression, but i am unable to figure out exact regular expression for this purpose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHPStorm, you can right click on a folder in the navigation window and click Replace in Path

Regex: `[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}` should match all email addresses.

Comment: He is looking for a regex which will match all email addresses.

Comment: by email types i mean all type of email address e.g user1@gmail.com, user1@yahoo.com, user1@hotmail.com.........something@something.com

Comment: A regex like `[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}` should match all email addresses.

Comment: You are awesome Devon :) you made my day.

Comment: A regex for email is much more longer than this. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/703068/372239

Comment: Yes, it is possible the regex I posted will miss some but I'm pretty sure it covers the large majority.  Matching all alphanumeric, ., %, +, -, and _ in the username, matching all alphanumeric, ., and - in the domain.