# unable to use CustomValidators with Clearance gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-validators, clearance, thoughtbot

We have recently started to use the Clearance gem, but are running into a few issues whereby my custom validations are no longer working

**Validations**

```
  validates :first_name,  presence: true, if: :registered_user?,
            format:   { with: CustomValidators::Names.name_validator },
            length:   { maximum: 30 }
  validates :last_name,   :presence => true, :if => :registered_user?,
            :format   => { :with => CustomValidators::Names.name_validator },
            :length => { :maximum => 35 }
  validates :email,       :presence => true,
            :uniqueness => true,##  This should be done at the DB this is too expensive in rails
            :format   => { :with => CustomValidators::Emails.email_validator },
            :length => { :maximum => 255 }
  validates :mobile,       :presence => true,
            :uniqueness => true,##  This should be done at the DB this is too expensive in rails
            :format   => { :with => CustomValidators::Numbers.phone_number_validator },
            :length => { :maximum => 10 }
```

**custom_validators.rb**

```
module CustomValidators
  class Emails
    # please refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703060/valid-email-address-regular-expression
    def self.email_validator
      /\A(|(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})\z/i
    end
  end

  class Numbers
    # validates australian numbers
    def self.phone_number_validator
      /\A(04[0-9]{8})\z/
    end

    # validates australian postcodes
    def self.postcode_validator
      /^(0[289][0-9]{2})|([1345689][0-9]{3})|(2[0-8][0-9]{2})|(290[0-9])|(291[0-4])|(7[0-4][0-9]{2})|(7[8-9][0-9]{2})$/
    end
  end

  class Names
    def self.name_validator
      #/([a-zA-Z-’'` ].+)/ \A and \z
      #/^([a-z])+([\\']|[']|[\.]|[\s]|[-]|)+([a-z]|[\.])+$/i
      #/^([a-z]|[\\']|[']|[\.]|[\s]|[-]|)+([a-z]|[\.])+$/i
      /\A([[:alpha:]]|[\\']|[']|[\.]|[\s]|[-]|)+([[:alpha:]]|[\.])+\z/i
    end
  end
```

**Clearance init**

```
Clearance.configure do |config|
  config.allow_sign_up = true
  config.cookie_domain = '.club.town'
  config.cookie_expiration = lambda { |cookies| 1.year.from_now.utc }
  config.cookie_name = "remember_token"
  config.cookie_path = "/"
  config.routes = true
  config.httponly = false
  config.mailer_sender = 'Cup Town <info@cup.town>'
  config.password_strategy = Clearance::PasswordStrategies::BCrypt
  config.redirect_url = "/"
  config.secure_cookie = false
  config.sign_in_guards = []
  config.user_model = User

  Clearance::SessionsController.layout 'landing'
end
```

Error Message

E

```
xiting
/Users/paulmcguane/RoR/barista/app/models/user.rb:77:in `<class:User>': uninitialized constant User::CustomValidators (NameError)
    from /Users/paulmcguane/RoR/barista/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/paulmcguane/RoR/barista/config/initializers/clearance.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/paulmcguane/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/clearance-1.14.1/lib/clearance/configuration.rb:177:in `configure'
    from /Users/paulmcguane/RoR/barista/config/initializers/clearance.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Can you define "no longer working"?

Comment: @Derek i am getting the following error Exiting
/Users/paulmcguane/RoR/barista/app/models/user.rb:77:in `<class:User>': uninitialized constant User::CustomValidators (NameError)
 from /Users/paulmcguane/RoR/barista/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
 from /Users/paulmcguane/RoR/barista/config/initializers/clearance.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
 from /Users/paulmcguane/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/clearance-1.14.1/lib/clearance/configuration.rb:177:in `configure'
 from /Users/paulmcguane/RoR/barista/config/initializers/clearance.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: @Derek do you any solutions on how to get this to work?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an issue with Clearance best I can tell. What happens if you prefix the class like so: `::CustomValidators::Names.name_validator`.